How to capture mutiple VueDatePicker data into single object in Vue3?
HTML Code:
<div v-if="isPlanDetailsAvailable">
        <div class="nav nav-tabs mb-3" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
          <button v-for="(plan, index) in selectedPlans" :key="index" class="nav-link"
                  :class="{ active: index === 0 }" :id="'nav-tab-' + index" data-bs-toggle="tab"
                  :data-bs-target="'#nav-content-' + index" type="button" role="tab"
                  :aria-controls="'nav-content-' + index" :aria-selected="index === 0">
            {{ plan.name }}
          </button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div v-for="(plan, index) in selectedPlans" :key="index" :id="'nav-content-' + index"
             class="tab-pane fade" :class="{ show: index === 0, active: index === 0 }" role="tabpanel"
             :aria-labelledby="'nav-tab-' + index">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="" class="label">Enrollment Date <span class="dim-light">(Optional)</span></label>
              <VueDatePicker
                  v-model="plan.enrollmentDate"
                  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                  :format="(date) => enrollmentDateFormat(date, plan)"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="" class="label">Effective Date</label>
              <VueDatePicker
                  v-model="plan.effectiveDate"
                  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                  :format="(date) => effectiveDateFormat(date,plan)"
                  @click="clearEffectiveDateError(index)"
              />
              <div class="error-msg text-danger">
                {{
                  this.effectiveDateErrors.length > 0 && this.effectiveDateErrors[index]
                      ? this.effectiveDateErrors[index]
                      : ""
                }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="" class="label">Termination Date <span class="dim-light">(Optional)</span></label>
              <VueDatePicker
                  v-model="plan.terminationDate"
                  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                  :format="(date) => terminationDateFormat(date, plan)"
              />
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Functions:
enrollmentDateFormat(date, plan) {
  return plan.enrollmentDate = this.handleDateChange(date);
},
effectiveDateFormat(date, plan) {
  return plan.effectiveDate = this.handleDateChange(date);
},

terminationDateFormat(date, plan) {
  const terminationDate = this.handleDateChange(date);
  plan.terminationDate = terminationDate;

  if (plan.effectiveDate) {
    this.isTerminationDateLessThanEffectiveDate(plan.effectiveDate, plan);
  }

  return terminationDate;
},

handleDateChange(date) {
  if (!date) return "";
  const day = date.getDate();
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  return `${month.toString().padStart(2, "0")}/${day
      .toString()
      .padStart(2, "0")}/${year}`;
},

isTerminationDateLessThanEffectiveDate(date, plan) {
  const effectiveDate = new Date(date);
  const terminationDate = new Date(plan.terminationDate)

  return terminationDate < effectiveDate;
}

Here I have multiple tabs and I am trying to capture each tab multiple VueDatePicker value into same object, the problem that I am facing is whenever I select one date value in one input(i.e. enrollment date) field it displays on that input field but as soon as I select next date in another input field (i.e. effective date) or the next tab enrollment date the selected data vanishes in previous tab input field as well.
How can I solve this?

Could you please reduce your lines of code to a [mcve] so that it's easier to understand more quickly? Remove everything that's not vital for the functionality you're trying to replicate. Thanks!
